# Protecting Ruby Code

Tags: ruby, security, source-code-protection

I'm developing a commercial project on an ARM based embedded board with a custom Linux kernel on it, using Ruby. Target workspace of the project and the device is a closed-environment, no ethernet, inernet, I/O devices etc... I want to protect my code/program so that; it'll only work on the specific machines I let (so; people cant just copy and paste my code/program on to their embedded boards and run it w/o permission). This can probably done with the machine's MAC address tho; I don't have any experience on the subject. I guess, just a simple if(device.MACAddr == "XX:XX....XX") wouldn't be depandable (not to mention people can just easily delete the check from my code). I can't use some ruby obfuscators, which I found thru google, beacuse; the device doesnt run ruby-external-C-libraries or such stuff, only pure ruby code.

So; what are your suggestions, what type of approach should I take?

Comment: JRuby can compile code to java .class files http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/JRubyCompiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is isomorphic to the problem of DRM.  You're giving a person both a lock and the key to that lock, and trying to stop that person from using the key in a way you don't like.

Therefore, I suggest using the same methods that other DRM users do: put your terms in the license, and sue them if they violate it.  You need to use the law to enforce the other terms of the license, anyway.

Answer (score 6):

you can't really protect it, its hard enough protecting native code!  and even then that basically fails if someone really wants to copy the software.

basically do very little if anything to secure it, its mostly wasted time and effort